# Handing in my application, along with its virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, python-venv

I have a python project that I am about to finish.
All its dependencies and packages are provided in my venv that sits next to my app (as it should). The project was developed through the venv. As expected.

My question is:
If I hand in my project and include the venv folder, will the user be able to run my program through the venv that I have provided?
In other words, if I instruct them to execute: `path\to\my\venv\python.exe path\to\my\app.py`, will it just work?
Is this a thing?

Optional bonus question: I'm on Windows. Assuming that my program is platform-independent, will this approach work if they're on linux? (I doubt it...)

Thanks.

Comment: One common practice is to put the dependencies into a requirements.txt file. If you run pip freeze > requirements.txt, all installed python modules will be written into the txt file

Comment: expanding on that, they create their own venv and run "pip install -r requirements.txt" and now they have the same venv (platform independent in theory, if the modules are)

Comment: @Endyd thank you very much. I didn't know much about this way of doing things. Makes so much sense.

Comment: @KennyOstrom thank you! See my comment above. I could not tag both of you in the same comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Endyd and Kenny Ostrom's comments, and some research, I'm aswering my own question for future readers.

**Virtual environments are not designed for this sort of task.** There is no guarantee that a venv will work properly after being transferred to another system.

The commonly used method is, rather, using pip to create a "requirements.txt" of your project via `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
The user will then create their own venv, and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to sync their venv with yours.

If what you want is an executable, there are certain tools like PyInstaller that you can look into.